# ASP.NET MVC is opensource but where is the source code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, open-source, codeplex

I read here it is opensource
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-1-0.aspx

but I can't find the link to download the source code.

Update: ok it's here http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

but why can't I see a visual studio solution to download ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support on an external website, not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

> http://aspnet.codeplex.com/

and don't forget to Thanks them :-)

```
svn co https://aspnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn
```

Comment: why can't I see a visual studio solution to download ?

Comment: On the right hand of Sourcecode screen. try to click "Connection instructions"

Answer (score 2):

a simple google search would've helped >

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Answer (score 1):

You have to browse codeplex releases. Here is the link for [MVC 3 source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781)